# Embedding a projective curve in a smooth surface (using a Bertini theorem)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $C$ be a reduced (not irreducible) projective curve of degree $d$ such that $C$ contains at most double points. By a result due to Kleiman and Altman, we know that there exists a smooth surface containing $C$. Can we compute $n$ (explicitly) such that for any $m \ge n$, there exists a smooth degree $m$ surface containing $C$? What happens if we assume that $C$ is smooth?

I was trying to solve this question in the following way: If I understand correctly, Theorem $7$ in "Bertini theorems for hypersurface sections containing a subscheme" by Kleiman and Altman, states that $C$ can be embedded in a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (because if the "embedded dimension" $e(C)$ is equal to $1$ (resp. $2$) then the dimension of $X_e$ is equal to $1$ (resp. $0$) by definition) and also gives a rough estimate for the value of $n$ stated in the question. But there should be an error in my understanding because if I take $C$ to be of the form $\cup C_i$ where $C_i$ are $-2$ exceptional curves and $C_i.C_j \le 1$, then it cannot be embedded into a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree not equal to $4$ (due to contradiction with the adjunction formula).
Could someone point out precisely, where I am getting it wrong?

**Note** $X_e$ consists of the set of points on $C$ with embedded dimension $e$.

Comment: The condition you wrote down is different from the minimum degree of a smooth surface.

Comment: @Sawin: You are right. I would appreciate an answer to either of the question. I am more interested in the second question.

Comment: What is your definition of "minimum degree"?  Certainly every such curve $C$ is contained in a smooth, proper surface that admits a very ample line bundle.  However, in order to talk about "the" degree, you need to first specify that very ample line bundle.

Comment: @Starr: I have removed the question using the term "minimum degree". I hope the present question makes sense.

Comment: There are at least two errors. One is in your definition of $e(C)$ -- it is 1 for a smooth curve, 2 for a nodal curve. Another one is: what is a $(-2)$-curve in $\Bbb{P}^3$?

Comment: @abx: Suppose that the curve is embedded in a smooth surface. Then $C^2$ makes sense. I am guessing you are trying to make a more subtler point which I do not get.  Could you kindly elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @abx: I have edited the question. I mistook $e(C)$ to be the dimension of $X_e$ (under the notation in the literature). But the theorem $7$ is still applicable. I still do not see where I am going to encounter problems.

Comment: @user43198 Note that the number $C^2$ changes if you see the curve $C$ as embedded into another smooth surface. So, $C^2$ makes no sense for a curve in ${\mathbb P}^3$. (Well, it makes sense and is equal to $0$.)

Comment: @user43198: I hope you see the problem now.

Comment: @abx, Anan'in: Thank you for the answer.